# ASP.NET Global Web Method Backend

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering if it is at all possible to make ajax calls to a global code-behind.

So if I were to make a call from `ExampleA.aspx` or `ExampleB.aspx`, is there a way I can handle those `[WebMethod]` calls, for arguments sake say in a `Global.aspx.cs` so I don't have to have duplicate functions in those example back-ends.

I am trying to use a `.ashx` page at the moment but I feel like I am taking the wrong approach. I feel like there could be a simpler means of achieving this.

**ExampleA.aspx and ExampleB.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Global.aspx/GetFoo",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            //Displays "Bar"
            alert(data);
        }
   );
</script>
```

**Global.aspx.cs**

```
public class Global
{
     [WebMethod]
     public static string GetFoo()
     {
          return "Bar";
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite follow what is the problem? Of course you can use ajax to get/post to same web method from multiple pages. What is your problem with this approach? Btw Global is not a good name (or even valid?) for this since Global.asax is asp.net application file/class.

Comment: Creating a web-service (.asmx) or generic web handler (.ashx) is the best solution for reusable code. You can also, go for WCF.  Aspx pages are for page creation and include page lifecycle and controls with page. Also, as Esko said one page can have Web-method and any page can call that method. There is nothing wrong in that approach too.

Comment: Thanks guys. Global was just an example Esko but thank you. I know an aspx can be used that way but for readability and workflow sake, I thought it would be better to somehow combine the code behind pages rather than them each have their own code behind.

My reasoning for achieving this by the way is because ExampleA and ExampleB are very similar pages that nearly have identical code for the most part. I've solved the front end duplication by simply merging the front end code into a .js.

Comment: You seem to be talking about inheritance, you should have base-page class that has the shared code and ExampleA and ExampleB -pages inherit that. that's object oriented programming.